# tradingeye JS error

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

Can anyone help me, I have a IE javascript issue.

I am really stuck and the client has just brought it to my attention.

The site is http://www.fleurofengland.com/, its the check out page so if you would be kind enough to goto the site, add anything to your basket and go through to the checkout.

The problem is when you get to the checkout page (https://www.fleurofengland.com/eaction/checkout.billing/), under the 'Billing and Delivery Details' heading you will see a dropdown called country.

Below that is another dropdown called County/State, this dropdown is meant to be populated from the values of the 'country' one above however its not working.

Please help or suggest a fix.

Thanks in Advance,

Kyle

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't get off the homepage. If you know what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not just IE. The following error is from Firefox:

Something goes wrong when accessing "ship_id_1":

```
document.getElementById("ship_id_1") is null
https://www.fleurofengland.com/eaction/checkout.billing/
Line 2773
```

Fix this and all should be well.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing to do with IE, it fails everywhere, so you can use debugging tools for any browser (eg. Firebug) to help you.

You're using `document.getElementById` to get references to elements with names starting `ship_` that appear nowhere on the page. Have you copied the script from a different form without changing the names?